# RequiredTargetFramework in C# visual studio not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

There are 3 issues with my Visual Studios project at the moment. The first one is that even though the RequiredTargetFramework is being set as follows

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

When I opened my visual studio, theSystem.Runtime.Serialization is still trying to find the dll in the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\ when it is supposed to find the dll at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0. I think it only considers this

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to decide which framework it is going to point to.

Another issue is this. When I open my properties,  the target framework does not include .NET Framework 3.5. It has 2.0,4,4 Client Profile,4.03 and 4.03 Client Profile but no 3.5. It seems that when I remove this line

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Then I can see 3.5.

Finally, I think this issue is related to the above. When I run nant, I am getting this error

1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Runtime.Serialization", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Runtime.Serialization" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime.Serialization".

What happen was that my System Administrator actually changed my user name from hong to huong but he/she forgot to change my home directory to that. I have changed my home directory but it seeems that the issue is still there. Can someone please help me on this. If not, I think i would have to format my computer. I seriously do not know why visual studios have so much dependencies.

Comment: You are chasing the wrong solution.  Core issue is that 3.5 doesn't show up in the combobox.  Forcing to build with 3.5 anyway is going to produce these problems.  Hard to guess what's wrong with your machine.

Comment: You think I have to reformat my machine? Seriously, I am really getting a big headache on this. I dunno why when i remove projectTypeGuids, i can see the 3.5. I have tried various solutions like trying to change the regedit but to no avail. I even reinstalled the entire VS.

Comment: The crazy thing about this is that when i change the targetframework to 4.0 all of the dll references to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\ even <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>.  points to 4.0.

Comment: I think the core issue is this. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Runtime.Serialization", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Runtime.Serialization" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime.Serialization

Comment: Can anyone tell me how we get the error above.